# Is curl of a position vector always zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curl

[image]
Now the thing is that the given expression is zero if and only if $x,y,z$ are linearly independent ...ie when $r$ is a free position vector... Now if $r$ is the position vector on a curve or a surface then $x,y,z$ are not independent .. Rather they are dependent and the answer shall never be zero..

Example if $r$ is a position vector of a point on the surface $x²+y²+z²=1$.. Which is the equation of a sphere.. There is obviously curling or rotation and definitely position vector is not zero..

Comment: The curl of the gradient of a function is always zero. That is what you are seeing.

Comment: No that is a easy case after all. I am asking a different question after all

Comment: Actually, if you take the antiderivatives of the three functions below and add them together then you have a function whose gradient is your vector field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curl operator applies to vector *fields* it doesn't make sense for individual vectors. the vector field you are interested is just a map $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $F=(F_1,F_2,F_3)=(F_1(x,y,z),F_2(x,y,z),F_3(x,y,z))$.

Let's break down this notation. For each coordinate $(x,y,z)$ the vector we end up getting for the $x$ coordinate, $y$ coordinate, and $z$ coordinate each individually depend on three functions. $F_1$ inputs the $x$ coordinate of the vector (and then outputs an appropriate vector), $F_2$ inputs the $y$ coordinate of the vector and $F_3$ inputs the $z$ coordinate. Combining this three, we obtain the vector $F$. Inputting every vector $(x,y,z)$, we obtain the vector field we are interested in. The specific vector field we get depends on the individual functions.

If we compute the curl of a general vector field, we end up getting $(\partial F_z/\partial y-\partial F_y/\partial z)\hat i +(\partial F_x/\partial z-\partial F_x/\partial z)\hat j -(\partial F_y/\partial x-\partial F_x/\partial y)\hat k$

The first component of your vector field is $x$, the partial derivatives vanish, as $F(x)$ is independent of $y,z$. The same happens for $F(y)$ and $F(z)$. So the curl of our vector field is just the zero vector $(0,0,0)$, and so $curl(F)=0$

More generally, if the first coordinate of your vector field only depends on $x$, the second only depends on $y$ and the third only depends on $z$, the curl will be zero.

If you want to think about something interesting relating to curl, consider the following:

If your vector field is of the form $F=(F(x), F(y), F(z))$, the curl will be zero, however there are other ways to obtain zero curl. Can you find these examples? Can you find a *general* rule for when the curl of a vector field would be zero?